# What alternative exist to write specialized forward-sexp-function?

Tags: motion, balanced-parentheses

I'd like to write code that allows `forward-sexp` and `backward-sexp` commands to navigate across balanced keyword-based expressions, such as make files that use the `if` / `fi` keywords.

It's possible to extend these commands by writing a specialized `forward-sexp-function`.

Aside from writing the logic directly, is there any package that already do that so I would not re-invent the wheel?

Comment: FWIW it looks like `sh-script.el` handles this by binding `forward-sexp-function` to `smie-forward-sexp-command` and I guess that the `smie` declarations do the rest.

Comment: @phils `smie` has been on my to-learn list for some time.  I should take a look. From what I can see that requires a syntax definition and it handles much more that just the pair matching which could be done with a iterative loop regexp search and count. I wonder if there are other packages that provide just the pair matching logic.